# Create link to liferay page in Webcontent

Tags: ckeditor, liferay

I'm new to Liferay. I'm using Liferay 6.0.5 CE.

I created some pages, each with some webcontent.

I want to create a link in a webcontent, which points to another page.

In the webcontent editor, I found the link creator, but I can select only images and documents, not pages. Or creating links to external sites, using their absolute URLs.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the "Browse Server" mask, see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: But I only have Document and Image in my dropdown menu.
  What's wrong?

Comment: I have Liferay 6.1, may be that was changend.

Comment: you can write the link manualy, something like `/web/guest/my-page` or `/group/my-group/my-private-page`